# What is an example of a basic solution which is not feasible?

Tags: linear-programming, discrete-optimization

In a course of Discrete optimization, we made the distinction between Basic feasible solution and basic solution:
A point z is called a basic solution of P if all equality constraints of P are active at z and a total of n linearly independant (equality or inequality) constrains are active. If, in addition, z $\in$ P, then it is called a basic feasible solution (BFS)
But have you an example of Basic solution that is not feasible ?

Comment: The optimal solution may suggest that you produce a fractional number of units.  This is not feasible.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=2$ and consider the following linear constraints:
\begin{align}
z_1 &\le 1\\
z_2 &\le 1\\
z_1+z_2 &\le 1
\end{align}
What can you say about $z=(1,1)$?